# Sharepoint 2010 SP2 and IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, service-pack-2

I'm trying to figure out what changes in SP2 apply to IE10. They note that SP2 adds support for IE10 but never really indicate what those changes are. I can see 3 direct things listed in the [excel file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/9/959F3A24-80B3-4930-8FF8-D3C631BB878F/Microsoft%20Office%20and%20SharePoint%202010%20Service%20Pack%202%20Changes.xlsx) they link. Are these the only changes? Are there more and if so are they documented anywhere?

Comment: I would suspect that yes those three changes are the only changes for IE10. "Windows 8 users with Internet Explorer 10 receive an error when trying to open a document from SharePoint 2010 directly in the Office client.", "Spell Checker doesn't work properly with Internet Explorer 10.", "When using Internet Explorer 10 in the "modern" mode on Windows 8, the open/edit-in-client functionality does not work for Office documents in the Office Web Apps or in a document library in SharePoint 2013."